# Can't force page break in posterdown (RMarkdown)

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using the `posterdown` package in R to generate a report. My YAML and code is as follows

````
---
# Don't change anything from line 4 to 50 unless you know how to read it. Its the formatting
# for the report (all the colours, fonts etc)
title: <br> **Namibia Inflation Forecast Report** 
author:
  - name: Research & Financial Sector Development, Bank of Namibia    
affiliation:
    address: <br> **Updated - `r format(Sys.time(), '%B, %Y')`**
title_textsize: "85pt"
author_textsize: "60pt"
column_numbers: 3
logoright_name: Logo.png
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{caption}
    - \captionsetup{font=Huge}
output: 
  posterdown::posterdown_html:
    self_contained: false
columnline_width: "3mm"
columnline_style: dashed
primary_colour: "#6d1d26"
secondary_colour: "#6d1d26"
accent_colour: "#6d1d26"
title_textcol: "#c7af76"
author_textcol: "#c7af76"
affiliation_textcol: "#c7af76"
knit: pagedown::chrome_print
---

<style>
  p.caption {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  #main-img-left {
 padding: 10px;
}
</style>


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```


```{r include=FALSE}
rm(list = ls())
source(paste0(getwd(), "/Code/LoadPackages.R")) # Check this out in the Code folder if you want to add R packages that you might need
LoadPackages()
source("Code/Tables.R", local = knitr::knit_global()) # Link to Tables code
source("Code/Charts.R", local = knitr::knit_global()) # Link to Charts Code
```

<!-- Here is where the report starts. You will notice that Each section begins with a hashtag (#), so that's how you add a title. If you want to add a subsection, you would use two hashtags. Basically, what I've done is just use the charts and tables that I've precoded in the 'Code' folder and then I pasted them into the report-->

<!-- For the Inflation Overview section, you can just change the text herein -->


# Inflation Overview

<span style="color: #6d1d26;font-weight: bold">Domestic Inflation</span> - Domestic annual headline inflation slowed to 6.9 percent in December 2022 (from 7.0 percent in November), which translates into a monthly inflation rate of 0.3 percent. The biggest contributors towards the annual rise in prices were the Transport (2.2 percentage points), Alcoholic Beverages and Tobacco (0.6 percentage points), and Housing, water, electricity, gas and other fuels (0.2 percentage points).

<span style="color: #6d1d26;font-weight: bold">Short Term Forecasts</span> - The short-term inflation forecast is presented in Table <span style="color: #6d1d26;">2</span>, with annual inflation expected to remain flat at 6.9 percent in January 2023 before declining to 6.6 percent and 6.4 percent in February and March 2023.

<span style="color: #6d1d26;font-weight: bold">Medium Term Forecasts</span> - Through the medium term, our baseline estimates suggest that inflation will average 5.2 percent and 4.3 percent in 2023 and 2024 respectively (see Figures \@ref(fig:fig1) and \@ref(fig:fig2)). 

<!-- Here is the first table (Bloomberg Forecasts) -->

```{r table1, echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, results = 'asis', fig.pos='!h'}

date <- read_excel(path = 'Data/Dataset.xlsx', sheet = 'Bloomberg Forecasts') %>% 
        dplyr::slice(tail(row_number(), 1)) %>% 
        dplyr::select(`Date of Forecasts`) %>% 
        dplyr::mutate(`Date of Forecasts` = format(`Date of Forecasts`, format = '%d %B %Y'))

bloomberg_forecasts %>% 
                  kable(format='html',booktabs=TRUE, align = "lccccc", 
                        caption = "International Price Forecast Summary", escape=F) %>% 
                  kable_styling(font_size = 45) %>% 
                  gsub("font-size: initial !important;",   "font-size: 35pt !important;", .) %>% 
                  row_spec(0,bold=T,color = 'white', background = '#6d1d26') %>% 
                  column_spec(1, bold=T) 
```

\newpage

# Short and Medium Term Forecasts

I want this section to be on a new page
````

In the past, I used to be able to force a pagebreak between sections (where the section would go to the start of the next column in my report) by just using the LaTeX command `\newpage`. However, now when I'm trying to force the last section in my report to the next column, it's not working. Any ideas on how to fix this?

This is how it looks right now (short and medium term forecasts section doesn't want to force to a new column)

[image]

and this is how I need it to look (I always used to be able to force sections to move to the start of a new page (or column in this case)

[image]